# jQuery autocomplete enter key issue

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a text box for searching using jQuery autocomplete. When I type something in text box, it is showing the suggestions out of which none is selected.

I found out that **selectFirst: true** is not supported now. If I select an item in the drop down list and press enter, it is working fine.

The problem is that if user enters  **app** for apple and presses the enter key, it tries to submit the form with **app**. The form should only be submitted with one of the values from the drop down list.

I tried to disable the form submit on pressing enter so that I could submit form from JavaScript but couldn't find a solution.

Here is my code:

```
$("#searchtext").autocomplete({
    source: path + 'autocompletesearch?category=' + $("select[name='category'] option:selected").val(), 
    width: '500px', 
    matchContains: true, 
    select: function(event, ui){
        $(".searchform").attr("action", path + "fullproductinfo/" + ui.item.id);
        $("input[name='searchid']").val(ui.item.value);
        $(".searchform").submit();
    }
});
```

And my form:

```
        <form method="post" action="search" class="searchform">
            <div class="searchdiv">
                <input type="text" id="searchtext" name="searchtext"
                    placeholder="Search a product or a brand" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="searchbutton">
                <input type="button" name="btnsearchproduct" value="Search" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </form>
```

Note that there is `<input type='button'` and not 'submit', so default enter pressing should not work for form. It is the autocomplete i guess that is submitting the form on submit.

Comment: Would it be fine if like you expect `selectFirst` option to work, you can have the first option to be focused by default?

Comment: Yes, that would be best, but selectFirst is not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Then you want first item to `autoFocus`, you can use that option now:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ autoFocus: true });
```

Mentioned in documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

**EDIT**

Since you have enter key issue, you can try like this:

```
$(".selector").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      if($(".selector").val().length==0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
      }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jquery ui for auto complete, all you need is specifying the autoFocus: true option.

It will automatically select the first result and when hit enter key it will use the first result.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  autoFocus: true,
  source: function (request, response) {
    //your code
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    //your code
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue & this is how I resolved it

```
if ($(".selector").val().length > 0) {
var options = $(".selector").autocomplete("option");
var fromAutocomplete = false;

jQuery.each(options.source, function(index, device) {
if ($(".selector").val() == options.source[index]) {
    fromAutocomplete = true;
}
});

if (!fromAutocomplete) {
$(".selector").val("");
    $(".selector").attr("disabled", false);
    return false;
}
}
```